# Como Inserir selectInput em todo o dataTable

Tags: r, shiny

Estou utilizando o shiny.
Como posso exibir um **selectInput**, com opções de 1 à 5, em todas as células de um **DT::dataTable**?

Tudo que estou conseguindoo é exibir é a tag *div*, através do *vlr[i]* dentro do *for*.

```
library(shiny)  
library(DT)  

ui <- fluidPage(  
   DT::dataTableOutput("tbl")  
)  

server <- function(input, output, session) {  

output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(  
    options = list(pageLength = 25), {
    n_rows <- c(1:15)
    n_cols <- c(1:10)

    vlr <- c()  
    n_elem <- (length(n_rows)*length(n_cols))  
    for(i in 1:n_elem){  
       #vlr_of_cc[i] = paste("vlr",i,sep = "_")  
        vlr[i] <- selectInput(paste("vlr",i,sep = "_"), label = NULL, c(0:5), selected = "0")  
    }  

    df <- as.data.frame(matrix(vlr, nrow = 15, ncol = 10, byrow = T, dimnames = list(n_rows, n_cols)))  
})  
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

obrigado.

Comment: Olá Fernando, você pode dar mais detalhes sobre o que você está tentando fazer? Sua pergunta não está clara. Obrigado

Comment: Seria como no link ( rstudio.github.io/DT/011-radio.html ), porém com select ao invés do radio.

muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Inicialmente eu gostaria de salientar que o exemplo que você colocou gera um dataTable **ESTÁTICO**. Assim, ainda que você conseguisse substituir o seu  por um tipo de entrada em HTML, seja um botão ou um select de lista, AINDA ASSIM, você ia ter que encontrar uma forma de mandar esses dados para o Shiny.

**TROCANDO O INPUT com o DataTable**

Eu peguei o exemplo que você [citou](http://%20rstudio.github.io/DT/011-radio.html) e mudei para ficar com uma lista ao invés do radiobutton. Segue um exemplo de código que troca o input por uma lista:

```
library(shiny)  
library(DT)  

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    m = matrix(
      as.character(1:5), nrow = 12, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(month.abb, LETTERS[1:5])
    )
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
      m[i, ] = sprintf(
        '<select name="%s">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          </select>',
        month.abb[i], m[i, ]
      )
    }
    m
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      m, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.cells().every(function(i, tab, cell) {
          var $this = $(this.node());
          $this.attr('id', this.data());
          $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
        });
        Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
        Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      sapply(month.abb, function(i) input[[i]])
    })
  }
)
```

Isso vai gerar um app assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o problema é que com esse código só é possível pegar os exemplos da lista na primeira coluna. Eu não achei um modo fácil de pegar elemento por elemento da tabela. E também note que essa tabela no exemplo que você citou tinha função de retornar SOMENTE UM NÚMERO POR LINHA. Eu teria que pensar melhor como acessar as células do dataTable dentro do Shiny.

**SOLUÇÃO ALTERNATIVA**

Eu acredito que para o problema que você quer resolver existe um outro pacote que é o IDEAL. Esse pacote é o [rhandsontable](http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/). Veja um exemplo de uma tabela gerada por ele:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que gerou essa tabela foi este:

```
DF = data.frame(integer = 1:10,
                numeric = rnorm(10),
                logical = rep(TRUE, 10), 
                character = LETTERS[1:10],
                factor = factor(letters[1:10], levels = letters[10:1], 
                                ordered = TRUE),
                factor_allow = factor(letters[1:10], levels = letters[10:1], 
                                      ordered = TRUE),
                date = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rhandsontable(DF, width = 600, height = 300) %>%
  hot_col("factor_allow", allowInvalid = TRUE)
```

A grande vantagem é que esse pacote foi feito para gerar uma tabela para coleta de dados e interação do usuário. O DataTable é ótimo para mostrar dados e permitir filtragem, mas não é a ferramenta apropriada para este tipo de interação.

Por fim, gostaria de salientar que essa tabela é só o frontend, você ainda vai precisar de um método para exportar esses dados para o server do Shiny. Veja a [documentação](http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#shiny) do pacote para saber como fazer isso.